# Conformal mapping(Complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I was doing some conformal mapping problems, and I found this problem where I could not express $z$ so easily (quadratic formula gives complicated expression), and also I could not break it down in few easier conformal mappings. Any help would be very appreciated.

If given that point $z$ goes around unit circle $|z|=1$, prove that point $$w=\frac{z^2-az}{az-1}$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, goes around unit circle $|w|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to verify, that for $|z|=1$ and $a\in \mathbb R$ we have: $|z-a|=|az-1|$, hence

$$|w|=\frac{|z^2-az|}{|az-1|}=|z|\frac{|z-a|}{|az-1|}=1.$$